# more then one callback function

Tags: jquery, function, callback

Hi is it possible to have more then one callback functions?
My thought would be adding another function(){ but that didn't seem to work

Html:

```
<h1 id="randomid"> Fade in</h1>
    <p id="tekst">Hello World</p>
```

Script:

```
    $("#randomid").hide();
    $("#tekst").hide();
     $("#randomid").fadeIn("slow" ,
      function(){
        $("#tekst").slideDown("slow");
      }
   );
```

Comment: No, you're allowed to nest functions like that. What you have should work fine. In fact, it does - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/AA9Y8/

Comment: You can have an anonymous function which internally calls other functions, as you've demonstrated in your example.  In what way is this not working for you?

Comment: Hi sorry, I haven't been clear. I mean I want to add $("#randomid").fadeOut("slow") after the slidedown from #tekst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue to add functionality to callbacks and nest them very deeply if you desire -

```
$("#randomid").hide();
$("#tekst").hide();
$("#randomid").fadeIn("slow",function () {
    $("#tekst").slideDown("slow", function(){
        $('#randomid').fadeOut(1500);
    });
});
```

Here is this example at work - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/AA9Y8/2/